# How can you "unbake" a normal/displacement/bumpmap in maya

Tags: 3d, maya

I have a complete 3d model with all sorts of maps (to reduce geometry) added.

However I would like to 3d print the model and would like the additional resolution of the maps back in the geometry of the model.

(I'm aware that bump doesn't affect the geometry, is there a way to recreate that effect in 3d or convert it to a different map?)

How would I best, reverse the bake texture procedure?

My preferred 3d software is Autodesk Maya.

Comment: Best is not defined. Convert to tesselation on the object is easiest. Normal maps would first need to be integrated into a cumulative field int order to represent something real (bumps) as there is no such thing in reality.

Comment: It's been many years since I worked much in Maya; in modo I would "freeze geometry", which would generate a high or mid polycount Sub-D mesh using all applied normal maps, deformation maps, vector normal maps, displacement maps and bump maps to create the high poly geometry.
I'm betting maya has a similar function.